# GroupBy Query mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with values like the following

```
Name     DatePurchased     QuantityPurchased

A      2/3/2012             1
A      2/4/2012             1 
A      2/5/2012             2
B      2/2/2012             1
B      2/3/2012             2

I want to output the following

Name        DatePurchased         QuantityPurchased

A            2/3/2012               1
A            2/4/2012               2      // as I have purchased 2 upto this date
A            2/5/2012               4      // as I have purchased 4 upto this date
B            2/2/2012               1
B            2/3/2012               3
```

My query

```
SELECT Name,  `DatePurchased` , SUM(QuantityPurchased) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY DatePurchased
```

does not do the math right. I know whats wrong but can't figure out the solution.

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `SUM()` with `COUNT()`. This may or may not work depending on what results you get _currently_; please post the output your current query generates.

Comment: Count doesn't work either. I'll post my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT t1.Name, t1.DatePurchased, SUM(t2.QuantityPurchased)
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table1 t2
ON t1.Name=t2.Name AND t1.DatePurchased >= t2.DatePurchased
GROUP BY Name, t1.DatePurchased
```

This joins `table1` to itself within Name and such that `t1`s date is always at least `t2`s date, and sums up `t2`s `QuantityPurchased` (for each name,date in `t1`).

(Try performing the same query with `SELECT *`, and without the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to see the joined table. Then the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` will become clear).

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the answer, misread it the first time. Now I understand that you want a running total.  I believe something like this should work.

```
Select B.Name,B.DatePurchased,SUM(B.QuantityPurchased)
FROM Table1 AS A
INNER JOIN Table1 AS B
ON A.Name=B.Name AND B.DatePurchased <= A.DatePurchased
GROUP BY B.Name,B.DatePurchased
```

Comment: That's not what OP wants - they want a cumulative sum up to each date.

Answer (score 0):

hope it helps!

```
SELECT Name,  `DatePurchased` , SUM(QuantityPurchased) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY Name, DatePurchased
ORDER BY Name, DatePurchased
```